# Is java byte-code always forward compatible?

Tags: java, jvm, compatibility, jvm-bytecode

I understand that the byte code generated by version JDK X is guaranteed to work on JVM Y, provided Y >= X.

Does this hold good for all versions of JDK/JVM?
i.e Is it fair to expect class files generated by JDK 1 to work on JVM 11?

Referred to [JVM specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/), [JDK 8 compatibility guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html) and [Java 11 JSR](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=384)
Could not find a precise answer there.

Comment: Well, we can't see into the future, but so far yeah.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bytecode itself should work in future versions. Until now this holds true but nobody knows if this will be true for all future.

What changes, and can break your program, are changes in the API. Deprecated APIs may vanish in the future and then your program will not work anymore and may throw a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` when referencing such a method.

Comment: A reference to any spec/doc that discusses bytecode compatibility would be great.

Comment: @SarveswaranMeenakshiSundaram May check out this...? https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/csr/Kinds+of+Compatibility

Answer (score 5):

Java byte code is not forward compatible, JVMs are backward compatible. The difference between these properties is, that any future JVM may decide to drop backward compatibility to a certain older byte code version.

Java byte code has been designed in a way that such cut is rarely needed, but there has been a deliberate limitation of backward compatibility already. Starting with Java 8, the support for different semantics of `invokespecial` of Java 1.0 has been dropped. As [JVM Spec §4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1-200-E.5) states:

> The `ACC_SUPER` flag indicates which of two alternative semantics is to be expressed by the *invokespecial* instruction ([*§invokespecial*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokespecial)) if it appears in this class or interface. Compilers to the instruction set of the Java Virtual Machine should set the `ACC_SUPER` flag. In Java SE 8 and above, the Java Virtual Machine considers the `ACC_SUPER` flag to be set in every `class` file, regardless of the actual value of the flag in the `class` file and the version of the `class` file.
>
> *The `ACC_SUPER` flag exists for backward compatibility with code compiled by older compilers for the Java programming language. In JDK releases prior to 1.0.2, the compiler generated `access_flags` in which the flag now representing `ACC_SUPER` had no assigned meaning, and Oracle's Java Virtual Machine implementation ignored the flag if it was set.*

This does not imply that early Java 1.0 code doesn’t work in general. Only code relying on the outdated and now unsupported semantics of `invokespecial` of that early version will break.

Another change is that the instructions `jsr` and `ret` have been removed¹, however, this change has been tied to newer class file versions, so these instructions are still supported for older class file versions, so it doesn’t break existing code. But this could be a reason for future JVMs do drop the support for these older versions.

---

¹ [JVM spec §4.9.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.9.1):

> If the `class` file version number is 51.0 or above, then neither the *jsr* opcode or the *jsr_w* opcode may appear in the `code` array.

The `ret` instruction has not been mentioned, but doesn’t work without `jsr` instructions.